# Conditionally extracting the beginning of a regex pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of strings containing the names of actors in a movie that I want to extract. In some cases, the actor's character name is also included which must be ignored. 
Here are a couple of examples:

```
# example 1
input = 'Levan Gelbakhiani as Merab\nAna Javakishvili as Mary\nAnano Makharadze'
expected_output = ['Levan Gelbakhiani', 'Ana Javakishvili', 'Anano Makharadze']

# example 2
input = 'Yoosuf Shafeeu\nAhmed Saeed\nMohamed Manik'
expected_output = ['Yoosuf Shafeeu', 'Ahmed Saeed', 'Mohamed Manik']
```

Here is what I've tried to no avail:

```
import re
output = re.findall(r'(?:\\n)?([\w ]+)(?= as )?', input)
output = re.findall(r'(?:\\n)?([\w ]+)(?: as )?', input)
output = re.findall(r'(?:\\n)?([\w ]+)(?:(?= as )|(?! as ))', input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\n` in the input string are new line characters. We can make use of this fact in our regex.

Essentially, each line always begins with the actor's name. After the the actor's name, there could be either the word `as`, or the end of the line.

Using this info, we can write the regex like this:

```
^(?:[\w ]+?)(?:(?= as )|$)
```

First, we assert that we must be at the start of the line `^`. Then we match some word characters and spaces [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) `[\w ]+?`, until we see `(?:(?= as )|$)`, either `as` or the end of the line.

In code,

```
output = re.findall(r'^(?:[\w ]+?)(?:(?= as )|$)', input, re.MULTILINE)
```

Remember to use the multiline option. That is what makes `^` and `$` mean "start/end of *line*".

Comment: I didn't know about lazy evaluation but that was what I was trying to achieve in my mind. Thank you.

Comment: "lazy"  in a regex context doesn't quite mean the same as "lazy" in "lazy evaluation". Have a look at the link in the answer. @vj1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using regular expression as well.
Here is the code:

```
output = [x.split(' as')[0] for x in input.split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can combine the values obtained from two regex matches :

```
re.findall('(?:\\n)?(.+)(?:\W[a][s].*?)|(?:\\n)?(.+)$', input)
```

gives

```
[('Levan Gelbakhiani', ''), ('Ana Javakishvili', ''), ('', 'Anano Makharadze')]
```

from which you filter the empty strings out

```
output = list(map(lambda x : list(filter(len, x))[0], output))
```

gives

```
['Levan Gelbakhiani', 'Ana Javakishvili', 'Anano Makharadze']
```